# android receive two httpReader results at the same time

Tags: java, android, httprequest

I want to get data from an online API, but this is a very lot of data, (Translating 1000 words from english to a give language).

The problem is that the api gives a "url to long" when I send more than about 800 words so I want to request the data in two requests.

Can I send two HttpReader requests at the same time, and will it get in like a waiting line if they both want to call the setOnResultReadyListener on the same time or will the seconds result be dropped?

So is it possible to request two times at once, or should I wait till one is finished before sending the next request? (average respons time from the api is about 7 seconds)

The code I have at the moment:

```
final ListView listviewTalen = (ListView) (view).getParent();
    final Taal taal = (Taal) listviewTalen.getItemAtPosition(selectedItemPosition);
    view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(settingsView.getContext(), R.color.DarkGrey));
    List<OpgeslagenWoord> opgeslagenWoorden = db.getOpgeslagenWoordenByTaalId(8);

    // <----------------------------------------------------->
    // <      HTTP REQUEST OM 1000 WOORDEN TE VERTALEN       >
    // <----------------------------------------------------->

    HttpReader httpReader = new HttpReader();

    httpReader.setOnResultReadyListener(new HttpReader.OnResultReadyListener() {
        @Override
        public void resultReady(String result) {
            if (result != null) {
                JsonHelper jsonHelper = new JsonHelper();
                TextHelper textHelper = new TextHelper();
                List<OpgeslagenWoord> opgeslagenWoorden = textHelper.duizendWoordenStringNaarObjecten(jsonHelper.getTranslation(result), (int) taal.getId());
                for (OpgeslagenWoord opgeslagenwoord: opgeslagenWoorden) {
                    db.insertOpgeslagenWoord(opgeslagenwoord);
                }
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The words are saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "An error occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(settingsView.getContext(), R.color.white));
            talen.remove(taal);
            ((ArrayAdapter<Taal>)listviewTalen.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    String httpReaderUrl = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=";
    String alleTalenAlsString = "";
    for (OpgeslagenWoord opgeslagenwoord: opgeslagenWoorden) {
        alleTalenAlsString += opgeslagenwoord.getNaam();
        alleTalenAlsString += " _ ";
    }
    httpReaderUrl += apiKey;
    httpReaderUrl += "&lang=en-";
    httpReaderUrl += taal.getTaalCode();
    httpReaderUrl += "&text=";
    httpReaderUrl += alleTalenAlsString;

    httpReaderUrl = httpReaderUrl.replace(" ", "%20");

    httpReader.execute(httpReaderUrl);
```

Comment: how about you use post instead of get

Comment: And how do I give the parameters with the post request?